# making a custom shape using css

Tags: css, background-color, css-shapes, shapes

I'm trying to use CSS3 to make this custom shape using css3.

[image: shape]
<sub>(source: [mattieumoreau.com](http://mattieumoreau.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/forme.jpg))</sub>

I would like to add text over it, and the red color is the background of my website (it will be a background image, so it has to be transparent.

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
h1.elaborate{
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    margin:0 50px;/*50 being the width of the arrows x2*/
    padding:0 25px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
h1.elaborate:before,
h1.elaborate:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:25px solid black;
    border-left-color:transparent;
    border-right-color:transparent;
}
h1.elaborate:before{left:-25px;}
h1.elaborate:after{right:-25px;}
```

and use it as

```
<h1 class="elaborate">I am the elaborate title</h1>
```

Demo at http://dabblet.com/gist/9209450

(*and hover over the title at http://dabblet.com/gist/9209563 to see a sort of explanation of how it works*)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tl"></div>
    <div class="tr"></div>
    <div class="br"></div>
    <div class="bl"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
}

.tl {
    top: 0;
    left: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 25px solid #000;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
.tr {
    top: 0;
    right: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 25px solid #000;
    border-left: 25px solid #000;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
.br {
    bottom: 0;
    right: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #000;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #000;     
}
.bl {
    bottom: 0;
    left: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #000;
}
```

Here's a demo: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E93cu/)**

**[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/E93cu/3/)** with text and red background